# Error data must be of a vector type was null R

Tags: r

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. On Rstudio cloud everything works but in rstudio deskop appears an error.

```
myData <- read.csv('C:/Users/iwona/Desktop/myData.csv', header = TRUE)
print('wpisz numer województwa, dla którego zostanie przygotowana anliza')
h1 <- readline(prompt="0-Dolnoslaskie, 1-Kujawsko-Pomorskie, 2-Lubelskie, 3-Lubuskie, 4-Lodzkie,
               5-Malopolskie, 6-Mazowieckie, 7-Opolskie, 8-Podkarpackie, 9-Podlaskie, 10-Pomorskie,
               11-Slaskie, 12-Swietokrzyskie, 13-Warminsko-Mazurskie, 14-Wielkopolskie, 15-Zachodniopomorskie")
h <- as.numeric(h1)


months_prices <- vector()
prices <- vector()
dataSummary <- vector()
regions <- as.character(myData$Nazwa[5:20])
years <- 2006:2019
services <- vector()
#regions <- dataframe
serviceNames <- c('Ryz','Mieso wolowe bez kosci','Kurczeta patroszone','Kielbasa suszona','Ser dojrzewajacy','Herbata czarna, lisciasta','Podkoszulek meski bawelniany, bez rekawa','Oczyszczanie chemiczne garnituru meskiego 2-czesciowego','Wegiel kamienny','Olej napedowy')

#for(h in 0:15) # h for regions

#h <- 5
par(mfrow=c(5,2))
cumulative <- data.frame(years=integer(), prices=logical(), services=logical())
for(i in 0:9) # i for services
{
  for (j in 0:13) # j for years 2006-2019
  {
    for(k in 0:11) #k for months
    {
      months_prices[k+1] <- as.numeric(as.matrix(myData[5+h,4+j+(i*14)+(k*140)])[1,])
    }
    prices[j+1] <- mean(months_prices)
    services[j+1] <- serviceNames[i+1]
    months_prices <- vector() # empty
  }
  pricesForService.data <- data.frame(years, prices, services)
  cumulative <- rbind(cumulative, pricesForService.data)
  tmp <- cumulative[cumulative$services == serviceNames[i+1], ]
  plot(tmp$years, tmp$prices,
       main = serviceNames[i+1],
       xlab="Lata", ylab="Ceny",
       type = "l",
       col = "blue")
  mtext(regions[h+1], side = 3, line = -1.5, outer = TRUE)
}
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x)))
> list(names(x), : 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
> ```

Thank for your help

Comment: Hi, can you share a sample of your data please?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b-L5o8HP46Wl-NShT3w0CBGmCo6ZaiZD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you know that you can print the value of loop indices when an error occurs? That can help figure out whether it is related to an overrun or underrun with indices. You can also run `traceback()` to help find the functions that were being deployed just prior to your error. However, I get no error with Rstudio Desktop running under Ubuntu 18.04 and R 3.6.2 with that data.